# Removing text tweets from dataset in R

Tags: r, twitter, rjson

I am working on twitter dataset, I need to remove some tweets concerning a certain word. I have retrieved the tweets concerning this word and I saved those tweets in a variable called "removing". I need now to remove those tweets from my dataset, would anyone tell me how I can solve it?

Snippet of data [link](https://gist.github.com/Hana2020/a06b752da38489424279) and here is the code:

```
 library(streamR)
 library(rjson)
 library(wordcloud)
 library(tm)
 tweets = parseTweets("tweets.json")
 table(tweets$created_at)
 table(tweets$text)
 removing <- tweets$text[grep("The text tweet I want to
 remove",tweets$text,ignore.case=T)]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `grepl` to return TRUE FALSE from a grep string...

```
tweets <- subset(tweets, !grepl("The text tweet I want to remove", tweets$text))
```

Comment: but when I remove those tweets, I only remove the text tweets without removing the whole tweet structure such as " created_at, screen_name, etc". Do you have any idea how to remove the whole tweet structure. Because I am trying to save those removed tweets in a separate file.

Comment: `tweets2 <- subset(tweets, grepl("The text tweet I want to remove", tweets$text))`... that should save the tweets to a separate dataframe.